# Regex : Want to eliminate dash start case

Tags: regex, pcre

I have below conditions.

- It will search the term "page"
- It catches String page - with quotes
- It catches variable assignment like - `int page=1`
- It will not catch the Strings with dash - "page-context", "previous-page"

So I got sample like ...

```
int page = 1
int page=1
import common.abc.page.PageSize;
import common.abc.page.*;
document.aForm.page=1;
map.put("page", 1);
response.write("<a href=\"page=1\">");
pageContent
class="page-context"
class="empty-page"
<%@ page
<%@ jsp:include page
scope="page"
someObject.page();
int pageSize =  7;
```

And here is what I made to pursue the goal. `/\b(?!-)(page)(?!-)\b/mg`.

I works nice without one case - the one has dash right before the page.
`empty-page` should not match with regex. (Line 8,9,10 and the last should not matched)

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead and lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<!-)\bpage\b(?!-)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GiSjib/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!-)`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if we have `-` at left hand side of current position
- `\bpage\b`: Match exact word `page` (`\b` is for word boundary)
- `(?!-)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have `-` at right hand side of current position